# complete dplyr with missing ID

Tags: r

I understand how to use complete from tidyverse [tidyverse complete a dataframe](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html)

In the example they give:

```
df <- tibble(
  group = c(1:2, 1, 2),
  item_id = c(1:2, 2, 3),
  item_name = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
  value1 = c(1, NA, 3, 4),
  value2 = 4:7
)
df
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   group item_id item_name value1 value2
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>  <int>
#> 1     1       1 a              1      4
#> 2     2       2 a             NA      5
#> 3     1       2 b              3      6
#> 4     2       3 b              4      7
```

Is there a way of adding a group and completing? e.g. add a group 3 and complete the table.

For example, I have a df which I populate in a for loop to make a plot. The df is like so:

```
    variant     Location        Position      variable value      protein         Mutation.type
   FANCI_L605F    FANCI      chr15:89828441_C/T   B  0.45          L605F          nonsynonymous_SNV
   PLCG2_R953*    PLCG2      chr16:81969788_C/T   B  0.87          R953*                   stopgain
   STAT3_R278C    STAT3      chr17:40486033_G/A   B  0.38          R278C          nonsynonymous_SN
   FANCI_L605F    FANCI      chr15:89828441_C/T   C  0.45          L605F          nonsynonymous_SNV
   PLCG2_R953*    PLCG2      chr16:81969788_C/T   C  0.87          R953*                   stopgain
   STAT3_R278C    STAT3      chr17:40486033_G/A   C  0.38          R278C          nonsynonymous_SNV
```

I also have a vector of possible variable names:

```
all_var<-c("A","B","C")
```

I have worked out how to add any missing variables (I think):

```
new_df<-complete(df,variable=all_var,Position)

>new_df

    variant        Location        Position      variable value      protein         Mutation.type
       NA              NA        chr15:89828441_C/T   A   NA             NA            NA
       NA              NA        chr16:81969788_C/T   A   NA             NA            NA
       NA              NA        chr17:40486033_G/A   A   NA             NA            NA
       FANCI_L605F    FANCI      chr15:89828441_C/T   B  0.45          L605F          nonsynonymous_SNV
       PLCG2_R953*    PLCG2      chr16:81969788_C/T   B  0.87          R953*                   stopgain
       STAT3_R278C    STAT3      chr17:40486033_G/A   B  0.38          R278C          nonsynonymous_SN
       FANCI_L605F    FANCI      chr15:89828441_C/T   C  0.45          L605F          nonsynonymous_SNV
       PLCG2_R953*    PLCG2      chr16:81969788_C/T   C  0.87          R953*                   stopgain
       STAT3_R278C    STAT3      chr17:40486033_G/A   C  0.38          R278C          nonsynonymous_SNV
```

How do I now complete the variant,Location, protein, Mutation.Type?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Have amended my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use add a row by specifying the group and use `complete()` to complete the combinations, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 add_row(group = 3) %>% 
 complete(group,  nesting(item_id, item_name)) %>% 
 drop_na(item_id)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
   group item_id item_name value1 value2
   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>  <int>
 1     1       1 a              1      4
 2     1       2 a             NA     NA
 3     1       2 b              3      6
 4     1       3 b             NA     NA
 5     2       1 a             NA     NA
 6     2       2 a             NA      5
 7     2       2 b             NA     NA
 8     2       3 b              4      7
 9     3       1 a             NA     NA
10     3       2 a             NA     NA
11     3       2 b             NA     NA
12     3       3 b             NA     NA
```